# Constraint Integer Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints, binary-programming

I have an integer linear programming problem where i want to maximize over $\{0,1\}^n$, so i have the problem $$\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}c^Tx, \text{    subject to } x_i \in \{0,1\} \text{ for all } i = 1,\dots, n.$$
I now want to introduce a constraint to make sure that the ones in the vector have specific distances $d_1,\dots, d_n$. This means, I want a constraint that assures that when $x_i = 1$, then $x_{i\pm j} = 0$ for all $j = 1, 2,\dots,d_i$. With this I want to make sure that the elements which are chosen (the ones) are not too close to eachother.
I already found that when $d_i = 1$, I could formulate the constraint $0.5x_{i-1} + x_i + 0.5x_{i+1} \leq 1$. But already for $d_i = 2$ I was lost.

Does someone have an idea on how to do this? That would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the constraints
$$x_i + x_j\leq 1 \quad\forall i, j = 1, ..., n, i\neq j, |i-j| \leq \max(d_i, d_j)$$

This is stronger than the constraints you propose, since for $d_i=1$, we will have the constraints $x_{i-1} + x_i \leq 1$ and $x_i + x_{i+1} \leq 1$. By summing these two inequalities, you obtain your proposed inequality.

Comment: Thank you!! that was quiet easy! I will try to formulate the problem like that and solve it in Matlab, I am optimistic it will work out.

Comment: You can obtain these "conflict" constraints via conjunctive normal form (CNF).  You want to enforce $x_i \implies \lnot x_j$, which is equivalent to CNF $\lnot x_i \lor \lnot x_j$, which yields linear constraint $(1-x_i)+(1-x_j) \ge 1$, which simplifies to $x_i+x_j \le 1$.

Comment: Your $\min$ should instead be $\max$.